# cratedb set default value when creating a table

Tags: cratedb

I want to set default value when creating a table using cratedb, just like what it is in mysql: 
here is a column name phonenum: 
   phonenum int(11) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'PhoneNum'
I tried, but not working in the same way using cratedb, does anyone know this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of CrateDB 1.0.1 this is not supported yet.

Comment: thanks, do u know any doc description about this in crate.io? My version is the latest 1.0.5, guess the same